# iOS 10: "[App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction"

Tags: ios

I sometimes get this message in the logs of Xcode 8b3 when running my app, everything seems to work, but I'd like to know where this comes from. Google did not help at all.

Comment: Are you calling the UINavigationController delegate method:   fun navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) { }  ?

Comment: `willShowViewController ` is never called, no...

Comment: I get the same. I am using SpriteKit and SceneKit and suspect them!

Comment: I'm using neither SpriteKit nor SceneKit

Comment: Same error message but no SpriteKit or SceneKit or navigation controller stuffs. Edited storyboard with IB before this message appearance. XCode 8b2.

Comment: Anyone file a bug report? I'm about to.

Comment: same here is there any solution for that?

Comment: I'm having the same problem; not using UINavigationController delegates or SpriteKit or SceneKit, just a very basic single-view app.

Comment: get this after presenting a MFMailComposeViewController on iOS 10 devices

Comment: OpenGL ES app (single view), same thing on interface orientation change.

Comment: Simpe single view app, added a popover controller and this message started appearing

Comment: Please have a look at this reply.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39997761/6602495

Comment: im opening settings from my app, and when returned from settings to my app i get this always.

Comment: Dear god, make it stop.

Answer (score 286):

in your Xcode:

- Click on your active scheme name right next to the Stop button
- Click on Edit Scheme....
- in Run (Debug) select the Arguments tab
- in Environment Variables click +
- add variable: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do be aware that I was randomly getting no NSLog output to the Console and removed this again to fix it. This is more of the 'high-class' programming we are subjected to by the goons at apple.

Comment: For what it is worth, I get this message whenever an orientation change is made and i DO have the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE environment variable disabled.

Comment: And now, I can't see anything in Console Log?

Comment: Note : Adding this you won't be seeing NSLogs in console too.

Comment: `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` cause troubles if you are using OSLog for logging.

Comment: Isn't this like turning off a fire alarm?

Comment: Could someone please, explain this? Why we use it. Because we don't solve an error. We hide it.

Answer (score 190):

It comes from `+[UIWindow _synchronizeDrawingAcrossProcessesOverPort:withPreCommitHandler:]` via os_log API. It doesn't depend from another components/frameworks that you are using(only from UIKit) - it reproduces in clean single view application project on changing interface orientation.

This method consists from 2 parts:

1. adding passed precommit handler to list of handlers;
2. do some work, that depends on current finite state machine state.

When second part fails (looks like prohibited transition), it prints message above to error log.
However, I think that this problem is not fatal: there are 2 additional assert cases in this method, that will lead to crash in debug.

Seems that radar is the best we can do.

Comment: Can you ,please, elaborate on tools, which you used for debugging to get this private method name and its structure?

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov you may use Hopper Disassembler to find warning text in framework binary and references to this text from private method.

Comment: I also get this when the keyboard scrolls in and I have a controller subscribed to respond by resizing its views.

Answer (score 83):

Try putting the following in the `environment variables` for the scheme under `run(debug)`

```
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

Comment: I got this in the simulator when rotating the iPhone 7 using the hardware->rotate menu items.  This environment variable made the spurious message go away.

Comment: Where are environment variables?

Comment: The answer from @Foo below is useful because it includes the how-to details.

Comment: It also not print the constraint warning log

Comment: OP asked where the message comes from. Just saying how to silence it is not the right answer.

Comment: Indeed, this adjustment is a subject to NSLog output disappearance, consequently returning upon deleting _OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable_ from the **environment variables**. This observation was made earlier in some other posting.

Comment: The "IOS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable" answer turns off ALL logging! Just close the logging view if you don't want to see the log. Really ridiculous answer, amazing that it has so many votes! Does nothing to address the actual message. Our apps that heavily use core data work fine, these messages and others started appearing after one of the last Xcode updates. Sad that Apple can't resolve these type of issues.

Answer (score 13):

We can mute it in this way (device and simulator need different values):

Add the Name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and the Value `${DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE}` and check it (in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment).

[image]

Add User-Defined Setting `DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE`, then add `Any iOS Simulator SDK` for `Debug` and set it's value to `disable` (in Project -> Build settings -> + -> User-Defined Setting)

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me: I'm also seeing this in the console, despite already having disabled the debug activity mode as suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

To fix, I deleted the app from Simulator.

I also ran *Clean* first.

I do not think anything orientation-related triggered it. The biggest thing that changed before this symptom started is that a Swift framework started calling `NSLog` on worker threads instead of main thread.

Comment: Doing a clean worked fine at first for me when I ran it in the simulator without rotating it, but then soon as I tested again with a rotation command, it reported the same error.

Comment: I am using pan gestures and only get this error when changing orientation.

Answer (score -8):

```
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

This will also disable the ability to debug in real devices (no console output from real devices from then on).

Comment: You just copied an earlier answer (with less detail)

Comment: actually the TL;DR helps.