# Accelerometer in CoreMotion Not Working In Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

My app uses CoreMotion to allow the player to move when the device is tilted. It worked perfectly in Swift 2 but when I updated it to Swift 3 it has stopped working. I am not receiving any accelerometer updates.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main){ (data, Error) in
        if let accelerometerData = self.manager.accelerometerData {
            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 10, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said: "it has stopped working". I can only guess that you mean that it compiles and runs fine, but your handler is never called. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSError` has been renamed to `Error` in Swift 3, so please make your `Error` variable camelCase (lowercase in your situation). It should have been camelCase since it's a variable, anyways.

Here is a new version of the function with that and other minor errors fixed (**NOTE MY COMMENT ABOUT SWAPPING X AND Y**):

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { data, _ in
        if let accelerometerData = data {
            // IMPORTANT: Are you intentionally swapping x and y here? -----------> ↓
            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 10,
                                                 dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 10)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the original function with just the variable renamed (NOTE: There are a few programming mistakes in here, I don't recommend using it):

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in

        if let accelerometerData = self.manager.accelerometerData {
            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 10, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 10)
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: You should not use the main queue as your `OperationQueue` for recieving Accelerometer updates. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616148-startaccelerometerupdates).

Comment: I have tried using your solution but it still doesn't call the accelerometer, i do get a message in the log "if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction". Im not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the handler is not called? Try putting: `print("Got accelerometer data: \(accelerometerData)")` after the `if let accelerometerData...` line. Also, which version of the code are you using?

Comment: I'm sure that the handler isn't called, the log only displays `[App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction` Im using the code you suggested above

Comment: I'm sure that the handler is called, because [that log message can be safely ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39997761/3398839). Please research any errors you have before posting. Anyways, add a `print` statement right below the `didMove` function to make sure that the handlers are even registered. Also see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that it wasnt being called and i was able to track the problem to the view controller not loading the .swift file