# Access to UITextField in iMessageExtension Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift3, xcode8, imessage-extension

I added UITextField to my iMessage ViewController but when I press to edit it jumps to another screen and console print

> MessagesExtension[4795:86068] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

Answer (score 0):

First of all this message is `os_log`, and there is no need to track this message. So you can stop this message as well as other os level logs(If you are observing so much unidentified logs in Xcode 8) by setting `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` in schema of your targets.

**Target** > **Edit Schema** > **Run** > **Environment Variables** > `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` **disable**

[image]
[image]

For more detail about this message check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458170/ios-10-app-if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any)