# Unwanted Animations and Console Errors in iOS Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10

Since updating to the latest version of XCode (8.2 beta) I now have two problems (both only occur in the simulator, not when I run my app on my actual iPad).

1) When I rotate the screen in the simulator I get a ~5 second animation of the entire screen rotating, along with the following warning in the console:

`[App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction`

2) When I click on a button which bring a popover view (the same problem to both popover views in my app), it adds a strange quick animation with a "flash" of white at the end, and when I close the popover view it fades it's opacity with a 5 second animation with the following console warning

`[Warning] <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x7fa57c2274a0> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.`

There is also a 5 second opacity fade animation of the main screen of the app itself when it first boots.

I've read and tried other solutions to these problems on here, but none of the ones I've found help...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you file a radar and let me know the radar #? You can link to this SO post in the radar description.

Comment: @russbishop I don't know what you mean by "radar"? (still pretty new to coding and SO...)

Comment: Radar is Apple's bug reporting system.  http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Also, if you could include a sample project either in the radar or linked from here, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a) Slow animation

The slow rotation animation is a feature in the simulator which you seem to have activated accidentally. You can disable it with:

Simulator `Debug` menu -> `Slow animation`:

[image]

1b) Warning

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458170/ios-10-app-if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any).

2)

Do not animate `opacity`. Instead animate the `alpha` value(s).

Comment: I read and tried that before I posted my question.  That solution did not work for me.  Also, it does not address the 1st half of my question.  Both of these unwanted animations started appearing in my iOS Simulator runs only after updating to the latest version of XCode...

Comment: I will post a new question for this... because I just realized it has nothing to do with my project, the simulator causes the rotation animation (very slowly) even with no project loaded.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Only part 1a of this answer applied to my problem, but that was the correct answer.  I must have accidentally hit "CMD+T" in simulator around the time I updated XCode...