# iOS 11 Xcode 9 [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

Tags: ios, xcode

I have freshly installed `macOS High Sierra` and `xcode 9.0.1` and run a simple program by adding a background image to `imageView`. My program run safely but dont know why I am getting this in console:

> [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

[image]

I am using `Xcode 9.0.1` and `iOS 11`

I have reserached [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458170/ios-10-app-if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any), it was `xcode 8` & `ios 10` .

`Apple Inc` might have overcome to this bug yet or we will get this even in new & stable versions??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10: "\[App\] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458170/ios-10-app-if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any)

Comment: @Takasur this is an old question nothing can impact on this even i cannot delete this question, and this is totally different from something that have suggested

Answer (score 0):

I am with Xcode 9.1 which was released two days ago and a lot of weird bugs like this seem to have been fixed! Give it a try and if this behaviour  persist add some screenshots or particular environment configurations info (if there are) to the post!

I had strange issues with the Developer Tools but now everything seems to work again perfectly.

They've also fixed the rendering issues with the simulators, so I strongly recommend to update Xcode and see if you get this bug again.