# When selecting Contact in iOS can't show the MFMessageComposeViewController in same method?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to display the messaging window in the didselect contact method

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact])
```

The message view controller

```
  present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Some related message I'm getting:

> if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new
>   fences due to CA restriction

I think I'm doing something that I shouldn't, but please somebody enlighten me!

Comment: The error message is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458170/ios-10-app-if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Do you mean when you attempt to present the view controller nothing happens or just that you also get the above error message

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I looked at that too. Actually the error message may not be related.